# C3Js - X axis label text position

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I am trying to generate one chart using c3js. I am facing issue with x-axis label position. It is overlapping with the x-axis tick values. In the screenshot, Request Date is overlapping with date values.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Code:
jsfiddle.net/bhuneshwer/qe0kxwa1/6/

Comment: Could you post your code here or create demo at jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: @DmitryDemidovsky - jsfiddle url https://jsfiddle.net/bhuneshwer/qe0kxwa1/

Answer (score -1):

If you drop label position, text will be placed at right bottom corner of chart. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/La5hwwur/1/).

```
"axis": {
    "x": {
        ...
        "label": {
            "text": "Request Date",
            /* "position": "outer-middle" */
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that's appropriate for your case.